# How do I make a file name search that will delete all the files under that name,

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make a file name search that will delete all the files under that name.

I would like it to say in it what files would you like to search to day and i type in an example eminem and it will have a list saying found 320 files with file name eminem and it to list the file types eg 20 .img files name eminem 300 .mp3 files with the name eminem and then an option  saying would you like to delete these files.

another idea would a choice of where to search an example a memory stick and you can use this to search and delete all files. this was just and idea and i thourght it would be very useful i have found some code that will search for files.

i would like a nice into saying what would you like to search for and let you type in what you would like to search and it searches it and you will get a choice to delete them i would just find this very useful.

here is some of the code i have already

```
@echo off
DIR /s c:\eminem - superman.mp3
::and to delete it the code would be 
del /p /s c:\minecraft.exe
```

but my idea to this is make a file search deletion tool using batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
Title Searching by file name and delete it
Color 9E & Mode con cols=60 lines=3
echo(
set /P "file=Type the name of file to search : "
cls
Color 9D & Mode con cols=100 lines=100
echo(
echo                   Please Wait ... Searching for "%file%" is in progress ....
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Populate the array with existent files in folder
set i=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\%file%*.*" /s /b') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "list[!i!]=%%a"
)
set Files=%i%
rem Display array elements
cls
for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do (
    echo(
    echo file number %%i: "!list[%%i]!" 
    echo(
)
pause
echo.
Set /P "nbFile=Type the file number in the list above to delete or Type ALL to delete all files = "
If /I "%nbFile%" == "ALL" (
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do (
        echo Del "!list[%%i]!"
        pause
        Del "!list[%%i]!"
    )
) Else (    
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%Files%) do (
        IF "%nbFile%" equ "%%i" (
            echo Del "!list[%nbFile%]!"
            pause
            Del "!list[%nbFile%]!"
        )   
    )   
)   
pause
exit
```